# How to read private variable from C# dll using python

Tags: python, c#

Below is the C# code:

```
namespace CreateProperty
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
        }

        private List<int> test_variable = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
}
```

I want to access value of "test_variable" in python code.
Below is the python code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('CreateProperty')
from CreateProperty import TestClass

obj = TestClass()
var_value = obj.test_variable
```

Above code is throwing error:
`AttributeError: 'TestClass' object has no attribute 'test_variable'`

How can I achieve it ?

**Note:**
We can access same in other c# project using below code:

```
TestClass reader = new TestClass();
FieldInfo field = typeof(TestClass).GetField("test_variable ", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
IList<int> var_value = (IList<int>)field.GetValue(reader);
```

var_value = [1,2,3]

Comment: I hardly think that's possible since the whole point of privacy is exactly to avoid access from the outside.

Comment: private members aren't meant to be accessed from outside the class. Are you sure there's no other way to do what you want to do without accessing private members?

Comment: in the same way as in .NET ... via reflection (but it defeat using private)

Comment: I have updated my question. (added note point). Please check once.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Private variables are hidden for a reason. If you need access to it then there should be a public function or property for you to retrieve it. If you need to resort to reflection to get this data then I'd take an assumption that your code is flawed